# MP3 codec restrictions

Tags: technology

I would like to ask what the patent and or licensing restrictions of the MP3 file format are, and when did these arise?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is within scope for patents. I'll migrate it, but it may get rejected...

Answer (score 2):

The compression and decompression algorythms of MP3 are patented by the owner, Fraunhofer-Gesellschaft, and thus are not freely available for commercial products or commercial use of the technology. personal use of the MP3-software is allowed. Open-source-encoders and decoders are being allowed.

a patent-free alternative for MP3 is OGG Vorbis. other alternatives are free for non-commercial use, like SHN and FLAC, but in controdiction with MP3, those two don't loose quality, while MP3 does.

[EDIT]
woops! I just realised I forgot to source this!
source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing.2C_ownership_and_legislation

Comment: FLAC is an open format with royalty-free licensing (not only for non-commercial use). SHN is an obsolete format. And as you said, these are lossless codecs, not alternatives to MP3. Both Opus and Vorbis are supposed to be patent-free modern alternatives to lossy codecs.

Comment: @Pere FLAC is indeed a lossless codec, though it does compress the audio by 30-50% and could thus server as a replacement to MP3, for as far as SHN goes, it's not being updated and there are codexes way better than it, that doesn't mean it can't be a replacement for MP3 if neccesary, though FLAC would be much better option. either way, both codexes do compress and can replace MP3 for that reason

Comment: in some cases (i.e. MP3 320kpbs) FLAC may be seen as an alternative. But for most cases, the royalty-free alternatives to MP3 are Vorbis and Opus.

Answer (score 1):

> The MPEG-LA group and Sisvel (Philips) prevent developers from adding
>   MP3 support to their software packages without paying royalties.

from http://en.swpat.org/wiki/Mp3

> MP3 has at least three separate companies that claim to have patents,
>   Alcatel-Lucent, Thompson and AudioMPEG. All their claimed US MP3
>   patents are listed in the automatically generated MP3 patent list. The
>   last of these patents expires in April of 2017. If you only look at
>   the MP3 patents filed before December 1992 (one year after the
>   decoding spec was published), then the last decoding patent expires in
>   September of 2015. AudioMPEG claims that their patents cover MPEG-1
>   layers 1,2 and 3. The other companies just talk about Layer 3. So, at
>   the minimum, fully decoding and encoding MPEG-1 audio is patented.

from http://www.osnews.com/story/24954/US_Patent_Expiration_for_MP3_MPEG-2_H_264/

TL;DR: All MP3 patents could have expired in US after April 2017.